# Can't open file created with Google Drive API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need to create a document using Google Drive API, then give writer permission to logged in user and redirect them to created file. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
$credentials = storage_path('credentials.json');
$user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
$token = [
    'access_token'  => $user->token,
    'refresh_token' => $user->refreshToken,
    'expires_in'    => $user->expiresIn
];
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Sheets');
$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Docs::DRIVE, Google_Service_Docs::DOCUMENTS]);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAuthConfig($credentials);
$client->setAccessToken($token);
$service = new Google_Service_Docs($client);
$serviceDrive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$body = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    "name" => 'Testing ' . Lang::get('pls.export.name')
));

$doc = $serviceDrive->files->create($body);
$permission = $this->insertPermission($serviceDrive, $doc->id, $user->email, 'user', 'writer');
$url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" . $doc->id . "/edit#";
return Redirect::away($url);
```

This is the `insertPermission` function

```
function insertPermission($service, $fileId, $value, $type, $role)
{
    $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $newPermission->setEmailAddress($value);
    $newPermission->setType($type);
    $newPermission->setRole($role);
    if ($role == 'owner') {
        $permission = $service->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission, array('fields' => 'id', 'transferOwnership' => 'true'));
    } else {
        $permission = $service->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission);
    }
    if ($permission) {
        return $permission;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

After I run this code, I can see that the file was indeed created (I can get its id too), I also receive a notification on email that the file was shared with me, but I can't open the file itself. I'm getting a notification that page does not exist and "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time".

P.S. The same approach works perfectly fine when I'm creating a spreadsheet, instead of document. I can access the spreadsheet without any issues afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and testing I managed to fix the issue. The problem was I was using google drive api to create the file. Instead, I used Google Docs API like so:

```
$document = new Google_Service_Docs_Document(array(
    'title' => 'Testing ' . Lang::get('pls.export.name')
));
$document = $service->documents->create($document);
```

Everything worked like a charm